# Ruby/Rails - Is it possible to perform ruby calculations in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I'm trying to perform a calculation that looks to me like it has to be in the view so far.

In the view I have

```
<% for post in @user.posts %>
    <%= post.tasks.count / @projects.tasks.count  %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to display the a percentage....  When I place <%= post.tasks.count %> by itself it displays 2 and <%= @projects.tasks.count %> it displays 4.

But when I try to do <%= post.tasks.count / @projects.tasks.count  %> it displays 0 not .50 or 1/2.

The reason I'm performing this logic in the view and not the controller is that I would like to display the dynamic percentage for each iteration of the for loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're getting zero is that both numbers are integers, so it's doing integer division. If you convert the first to a float, then you'll get a float as the result.

If you want to format the number as a percentage, you'll also want to use the `number_to_percentage` helper as well. So your view code would look something like this:

```
<%= number_to_percentage( post.tasks.count.to_f / @projects.tasks.count ) %>
```

And would produce the output `50%` in your view. You can also specify the precision and some formatting options to that helper, if you need to customize it further.

Answer (score 4):

Integer arithmetic produces integer results. Try:

```
<%= post.tasks.count.to_f / @projects.tasks.count  %>
```

To get control of display precision and the like you might want something like:

```
<%= "%4.2f" % (post.tasks.count.to_f / @projects.tasks.count) %>
```